# Find groups that contain all elements, but do not overlap

Tags: r

I've been given a set of country groups and I'm trying to get a set of mutually exclusive regions so that I can compare them. The problem is that my data contains several groups, many of which overlap. How can I get a set of groups which contain all countries, but do not overlap with each other?

For example, assume that this is the list of countries in the world:

```
World <- c("Angola", "France", "Germany", "Australia", "New Zealand")
```

Assume that this is my set of groups:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("Africa", "Western Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Commonwealth Countries"), 
           element = c("Angola", "France", "Germany", "France", "Australia", "New Zealand", "Australia"))

                   group     element
1                 Africa      Angola
2         Western Europe      France
3                 Europe     Germany
4                 Europe      France
5                Oceania   Australia
6                Oceania New Zealand
7 Commonwealth Countries   Australia
```

How could I remove overlapping groups (in this case Western Europe) to get a set of groups that contains all countries like the following:

```
df_solved <- data.frame(group = c("Africa", "Europe", "Europe", "Oceania", "Oceania"),
                        element = c("Angola", "France", "Germany", "Australia", "New Zealand"))

    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
2  Europe      France
3  Europe     Germany
4 Oceania   Australia
5 Oceania New Zealand
```

Comment: so to be sure, you keep the first one right ?

Comment: Not the fanciest, but maybe `df <- df[order(df$group), ]` and then `df[!duplicated(df$element), ]`. At least this works for the example. On the other hand, if an initial group (lexicologically ordered) is super small, you could order first on group size and then on group name.

Comment: probably needs a set operation or count of occurrences to know which dupe to remove

Comment: No, I don't necessarily keep the first one. I keep whatever allows me to have all countries. In this case, it happens to be the first, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I'll add some more rows to my example to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Do you have a rule how the disjoint groups should be constructed? Otherwise, it will be impossible to decide programmatically.

Comment: with your new example all answers fail, and it will fail even when sorted,we need structured info on how Europe has priority over Western Europe and how Oceania has priority over Commonwealth, could be just a sorted array.

Comment: @uwe No, I don't have an algorithm to do it, I was hoping to find that.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper If you include Western Europe, you cannot include Germany anymore, so you canonly have Europe. The same applies for Oceania

Comment: could the Q be summed up by "keep the smallest possible number of groups while keeping all the countries" ?

Comment: @Cath Any number of non-overlapping groups will do, so smallest would be fine.

Comment: maybe just use the continents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If you want to simply eliminate duplicate elements then use `!duplicated(...)` as shown.  No packages are used.

```
subset(df, !duplicated(element))
```

giving:

```
    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
2  Europe      France
3  Europe     Germany
5 Oceania   Australia
6 Oceania New Zealand
```

**2) set partitioning** If each group must be wholly in or wholly out and each element may only appear once then this is a set partitioning problem:

```
library(lpSolve)
const.mat <- with(df, table(element, group))
obj <- rep(1L, ncol(const.mat))
res <- lp("min", obj, const.mat, "=", 1L, all.bin = TRUE)
subset(df, group %in% colnames(const.mat[, res$solution == 1]))
```

giving:

```
    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
2  Europe      France
3  Europe     Germany
5 Oceania   Australia
6 Oceania New Zealand
```

**3) set covering** Of course there may be no exact set partition so we could consider the set covering problem (same code exceept "=" is replaced by ">=" in the lp line.

```
library(lpSolve)

const.mat <- with(df, table(element, group))
obj <- rep(1L, ncol(const.mat))
res <- lp("min", obj, const.mat, ">=", 1L, all.bin = TRUE)
subset(df, group %in% colnames(const.mat[, res$solution == 1]))
```

giving:

```
    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
2  Europe      France
3  Europe     Germany
5 Oceania   Australia
6 Oceania New Zealand
```

and we could optionally then apply (1) to remove any duplicates in the cover.

**4) Non-dominated groups** Another approach is to remove any group whose elements form  a strict subset of the elements of some other group.  For example, every element in Western Europe is in Europe and Europe has more elements than Western Europe so the elements of Western Europe are a strict subset of the elements of Europe and we remove Western Europe.  Using `const.mat` from above:

```
# returns TRUE if jth column of const.mat is dominated by some other column
is_dom_fun <- function(j) any(apply(const.mat[, j] <= const.mat[, -j], 2, all) & 
                            sum(const.mat[, j]) < colSums(const.mat[, -j]))

is_dom <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(const.mat)), is_dom_fun) 
subset(df, group %in% colnames(const.mat)[!is_dom])
```

giving:

```
    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
3  Europe     Germany
4  Europe      France
5 Oceania   Australia
6 Oceania New Zealand
```

If there are any duplicates left we can use (1) to remove them.

Comment: I've modified my original data to better display what I need. I don't need just unique values, I need disjointed sets that include all countries in the world.

Comment: Your second one looks like what I'm after, I'll check it against my data.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. The application of (4) and (2) allows me to remove groups I don't want and then focus on the ones I do.

Answer (score 3):

One possible rule could be to minimize the number of groups, e.g. to associate an element with that group which includes the most elements.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, n.elements := .N, by = group][
  order(-n.elements), .(group = group[1L]), by = element]
```

> ```
>        element   group
> 1:     Germany  Europe
> 2:      France  Europe
> 3:   Australia Oceania
> 4: New Zealand Oceania
> 5:      Angola  Africa
> ```

#### Explanation

```
setDT(df)[, n.elements := .N, by = group][]
```

returns

> ```
>                     group     element n.elements
> 1:                 Africa      Angola          1
> 2:         Western Europe      France          1
> 3:                 Europe     Germany          2
> 4:                 Europe      France          2
> 5:                Oceania   Australia          2
> 6:                Oceania New Zealand          2
> 7: Commonwealth Countries   Australia          1
> ```

Now, the rows are ordered by decreasing number of elements and for each country the first, i.e., the "largest", group is picked. This should return a group for each country as requested.
In case of ties, i.e., one group contains equally many elements, you can add additional citeria when ordering, e.g., length of the group name, or just alphabetical order.

Comment: It's a clear rule, but I can imagine undesirable side effects, like `DT = data.table(g = c("NA", "Caribbean", "SA", "Caribbean"), rep(c("Bahamas", "Grenada"), each=2))`, when maybe you wanted/expected to keep NA and SA and drop the Carribean. Generally, I think the OP should manually choose a set of groups to retain and then verify that they partition the elements (or achieve whatever property the OP is after) ...

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(element, .keep_all=TRUE)

    group     element
1  Africa      Angola
2  Europe      France
3  Europe     Germany
4 Oceania   Australia
5 Oceania New Zealand
```

Shoutout to Axeman for beating me with this answer.

---

**Update**

Your question is ill-defined. Why is 'Europe' preferred over 'Western Europe'?  Put another way, each country is assigned several groups. You want to reduce it to one group per country. How do you decide which group?

Here's one way, we always prefer the biggest:

```
groups <- df %>% count(group)
df %>% inner_join(groups, by='group') %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% distinct(elemenet, .keep_all=TRUE)

    group     element n
1  Europe      France 2
2  Europe     Germany 2
3 Oceania   Australia 2
4 Oceania New Zealand 2
5  Africa      Angola 1
```

Comment: Wow, within seconds of submitting the answer, it was down voted, together with the rest of perfectible usable answers.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't me - I modified my question to better give what I wanted and I think someone else came by and saw that the answers didn't match. Originally, sorting worked on my example dataset, but it didn't solve my actual problem.

Comment: At least, you should make a reference to [Axeman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240845/find-groups-that-contain-all-elements-but-do-not-overlap/46240935#comment79446049_46240935) who posted this solution 13 mins before your posting.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it after I submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, head(.SD, 1), element]
```

---

Or with `unique`

```
unique(setDT(df), by = 'element')
#    group     element
#1:  Africa      Angola
#2:  Europe      France
#3:  Europe     Germany
#4: Oceania   Australia
#5: Oceania New Zealand
```

Packages are used and it is `data.table`

Comment: I've modified my original data to better display what I need. I don't need just unique values, I need disjointed sets that include all countries in the world.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach would be to ignore the given groups but to look up just the country names in the catalogue of UN regions which are available in the  [`countrycodes`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=countrycode) or [`ISOcodes`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ISOcodes) packages.

The `countrycodes` package seems to offer the simpler interface and it also warns about country names which can not be found in its database:

```
# given country names - note the deliberately misspelled last entry 
World <- c("Angola", "France", "Germany", "Australia", "New Zealand", "New Sealand")
# regions
countrycode::countrycode(World, "country.name.en", "region")
```

> ```
> [1] "Middle Africa"             "Western Europe"            "Western Europe"            "Australia and New Zealand"
> [5] "Australia and New Zealand" NA                         
> Warning message:
> In countrycode::countrycode(World, "country.name.en", "region") :
>   Some values were not matched unambiguously: New Sealand
> ```

```
# continents
countrycode::countrycode(World, "country.name.en", "continent")
```

> ```
> [1] "Africa"  "Europe"  "Europe"  "Oceania" "Oceania" NA       
> Warning message:
> In countrycode::countrycode(World, "country.name.en", "continent") :
>   Some values were not matched unambiguously: New Sealand
> ```